# Angular 10 - Cannot get touch event from HammerJS

Tags: angular, touch, hammer.js

I want to integrate pinch gesture on a square div.

[Live example Angular 9](https://stackblitz.com/edit/pinch-gesture?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Problem, when I run it locally, npm start fails. I've managed to start it on Angular 10 through ng update. Then the library no longer works.
`ng update @angular/cli @angular/core`

1. - what is causing the issue (pinch event not working locally in angular 10) ?
2. - any hint to debug live js events?

[source](https://indepth.dev/gestures-in-an-angular-application/)